# Has code in getters and setters fallen out of favor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I see this over, and over in code samples for declaring a property.  **I understand this is utilizing the Automatic Property feature with an anonymous private backing field.**

```
public sometype somevar {get;set;} <-- nothing happening in the getter or setter.
```

But, I never seem to see an example like this anymore.  When I was in college 2000's in .NET programming stuff like this was used all the time.  The best example I can think of having a set of properties like Server,Database,User, and then another property called ConnectionString (This is just an example, I have no code like this)

```
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }



    public string ConnectionString 
    {

        get
        {
            return SomePrivateMethod(this.ServerName,this.DatabaseName,this.UserName);
        }

        set
        {
            this.ServerName = PrivateMethodThatParsesOutTheServerName(value);
            this.DatabaseName = PrivateMethodThatParsesOutTheServerName(value);
            this.UserName = PrivateMethodThatParsesOutTheServerName(value);

        }
    }
```

I was getting ready to do something like this I have a property called strap which is a text field that stores values like '0001020003', but I have a legacy system that can't interpret that strap format.  So I was going to do this

```
public string strap {get;set;}

public string legacyFormat {

get {
 return FormatForLegacySystem(this.strap);
}

//don't need a setter though

}
```

Then I thought, maybe this should be an extension instead...

```
public static string AsLegacyFormat(this string value){
 //formatting code;
return fancynewformat;
}
```

One last thought.  I was thinking this sort of a thing really belongs in my service layer.

```
public getLegacyFormat(string strap)
{
//stuff here
}
```

But, now it seems silly to have to wrap every instance of strap when I need to pass it in it's legacy format.  And tyring to use this approach with a property

```
Model.LegacyFormat = service.getLegacyFormat(Model.strap);
```

Well, that seems bad form, since LegacyFormat should be immutable based on my strap.

Comment: No they haven't, it's just that often you don't need them.

Comment: No, it has not fallen out of favor, at least not universally: I coded something like that in production a few days back. This does not make your question any less subjective, though: it appears to ask for an opinion rather than a fact.

Comment: Maybe I should retitle my question, do extension methods replace code in getters and setters?

Comment: Might be off topic, but in general I avoid making an extension method on a base type like `string` only because _all_ strings will now have a `AsLegacyFormat` member that can be called even if the string has _nothing to do with connection strings_. Unless such an extension method is being used only by few classes, and those classes are treating strings _predominantly_ (or ideally, _only_) as connection strings, I find it brings nothing but pain. But then again, I really prefer having very clean intellisense/autocomplete entries, so maybe I'm off my rocker on this :)

Comment: I tend to use readonly fields to back my properties, because many of my objects are immutable. Also, I make quite a lot of use of Code Contracts (i.e. `Contract.Requires()` and `Contract.Ensures()`). Clearly, naked autoproperty setters can't validate their value.

Comment: I find this question looking for a subjective opinion and asking for a discussion. Perhaps the chat is a better place for it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think code in getters/setters are out of style. I would recommend code in getters and setters as long as they are

1. Small
2. Do not cause side-effects
3. Are relevant to the property being fetched/set

I have also sometimes used virtual getters and setters for some classes to be able to modify certain kinds of behavior.

Sometimes, you gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned one extremely important aspect of property getters and setters: You can validate the property values.

I don't know about other people's experience, but the majority of my classes' properties have validation in the setters.

I use Code Contracts for this, so the setters will often have a `Contract.Requires()` and the getters often have a `Contract.Ensures()`.

A lot of my properties can't be null, so I use a Code Contract in the getter to express that fact, for example `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string> != null);`

So I think having code in getters and setters is quite important!

Answer (score 0):

ABSOLUTELY NOT!!! In fact, you will want to use this if you are using WPF MVVM applications. The preferred way for handling lets say a 'SelecctionChanged' event is to handle it in the get/set of the property, and NOT to use code behind.